# Intermittent RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

This is my rewrite rule in .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^quiz/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([0-9-]+)/?$ quiz/index.php?inv=$1&d=$2 [NC,L]
```

It works perfectly fine for these URLs, which have a mix of cases, with and without hyphens, and all with a date for the final segment:

```
http://localhost/quiz/C-PFM/2021-04-30/

http://localhost/quiz/cpf-o/2021-04-30/

http://localhost/quiz/ipa/2021-04-30/

http://localhost/quiz/ipacsc/2021-04-30/

http://localhost/quiz/uob-sp/2021-04-30/

http://localhost/quiz/uobsp/2021-04-30/

http://localhost/quiz/Hol-V/2021-04-30/

http://localhost/quiz/HOLVA/2021-04-30/
```

That is, `$_GET` is correctly returning e.g.

`inv=HOLVA; d=2021-04-30`

As expected.

However, the same rule fails (returns a 404) for each of these examples, which also have a mix of case, and some with hyphen, some without:

```
http://localhost/quiz/CPFM/2021-04-30/

http://localhost/quiz/cpfo/2021-04-30/

http://localhost/quiz/ipac-sc/2021-04-30/

http://localhost/quiz/GLD10US/2021-04-30/

http://localhost/quiz/HolV/2021-04-30/

http://localhost/quiz/OCBCC/2021-04-30/

http://localhost/quiz/PP/2021-04-30/
```

Some of the failing ones could be made to work by adding a hyphen in random places. I did actually try to escape the hyphen in my rule, like this, but it didn't seem to make a difference:

```
RewriteRule ^quiz/([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)/([0-9\-]+)/?$ quiz/index.php?inv=$1&d=$2    [NC,L]
```

I also tried removing `NC` or the whole `[NC,L]` and it made no difference.

I also tried both `+` and `*` after the first `[ ]` block, but that didn't make a difference.

The .htaccess file has no other relevant rules that could be conflicting.

Why are the non-working ones not working?

TIA

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples/attempts, could you please try following. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(quiz)/([\w-]+)/(\d{4}(?:-\d{2}){2})/?$ $1/index.php?inv=$1&id=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, but the bahaviour is the same.

I also tried one variable (without date), like this

RewriteRule     ^quiz/([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)/?$    quiz/index.php?inv=$1

The working ones from before worked, the non-working ones still didn't. So the date part is not affecting things.

Comment: @MBourne, could you please do give me 1 sample url for which it didn't work? Thank  you.

Comment: Thank you for your help. My original question has 7 examples where it didn't work and still don't with your suggested rule. The original ones that worked work with your suggested rule.

Comment: Solved it. My index.php actually involves creating .png images on the server. Turns out the early versions of my file (which generated the images only, not as part of an HTML page) were still in cache, even though I'm using 3 different browsers and I cleared the cache for each one. So annoying. I've now been able to finally clear things out and it's working as expected now. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: "Clear your browser cache" was the advice that nailed it eventually. For anyone that comes to this later, all 3 approaches (my original, anubhava's and yours) will work.

Answer (score 1):

You may also try a negated character class like `[^/]` that matches anything but `/`.:

```sh
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(quiz)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1/index.php?inv=$1&id=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

This assumes that there is no .htaccess inside `quiz/` folder. You can try this rule inside `quiz/.htaccess`:

```sh
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?inv=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hello Anubhava. Thank you for your suggestion. Please see my final comment on RavinderSingh13's answer. It turned out to be a cache problem. Grrr.